# I want to use Popover with a button in Swift UI, but the problem when there are multiple buttons

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

When popover View is displayed with Swift UI buttons, if there are multiple buttons as shown below, only the number of buttons

```
@State var isShowPopover: Bool = false
```

I think I have to prepare, but if there are multiple buttons, is it possible to do this with one instead of preparing for all the buttons?

```
struct PopoverTest: View {

    // Popover
    @State var isShowPopover: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
                   // First Button
                   Button(action: {
                                     self.isShowPopover = true
                                      }, label: {
                                        Image(systemName: "stopwatch")
                                            
                                      })
                                        .popover(isPresented: $isShowPopover) {
                                            Text("Popover1")
                                               .font(.largeTitle)
                                        }
                                        .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                   // Second Button
                   Button(action: {
                                     self.isShowPopover = true
                                      }, label: {
                                        Image(systemName: "rectangle")
                                            
                                      })
                                        .popover(isPresented: $isShowPopover) {
                                            Text("Popover2")
                                               .font(.largeTitle)
                                        }

        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Use `.popover(item:...)` instead and attach it to parent VStack, so each button assign different item value for state.

Comment: Use @Asperi suggestion with an enum, it'll be easier to manage your buttons.

Comment: How should I write in either case?

Answer (score 0):

try this approach, using `popover(item:...)` as mentioned by @Asperi. You can of course as mentioned in the comments, adapt this to use enums. See also https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/popover(item:attachmentanchor:arrowedge:content:)

```
struct MySelection: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var text = ""
}

struct PopoverTest: View {
    @State var selected: MySelection?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack (spacing: 88) {
            // First Button
            Button(action: {
                selected = MySelection(text: "Popover1")
            }, label: {
                Image(systemName: "stopwatch")
            })
            // Second Button
            Button(action: {
                selected = MySelection(text: "Popover2")
            }, label: {
                Image(systemName: "globe")
            })
        }
        .buttonStyle(.plain)
        .popover(item: $selected) { selection in
            Text(selection.text).font(.largeTitle)
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Thank you. With the above method, both are certainly displayed, but there is a problem that Popover is displayed only on the upper button. Is it possible to display a popover on each button?